# Android view flickering at the beginning TranslateAnimation

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I use TranslateAnimation to move buttons and it works fine, but before animation started strange flickering apear. For short time animated view moves to position higher then it is. After that view back to normal position and animation started.

I use RelativeLayout and move 7 buttons.

```
public void moveView(final int rotationType) {
    AnimationSet animationList[] = new AnimationSet[buttonAmount];
    for (int i = 0; i < buttonAmount; i++) {
        AnimationSet animationsSet = new AnimationSet(false);
        animationsSet.setFillAfter(true);
        boolean visible = true;
        boolean hide = false;
        boolean show = false;
        ImageButton button = buttons.get(i);

        int position = i + movementCount;

        if (position < 0) {
            position = getLastButtonId();
        } else if (position > getLastButtonId()) {
            position = position - buttonAmount;
        }
        int cL = getDP(leftCoord.get(position));
        int cB = getDP(bottomCoord.get(position));

        // TODO left right

        if (rotationType == RIGHTBUTTON) {
            position--;
        } else if (rotationType == LEFTBUTTON) {
            position++;
        }

        if (position < 0) {
            position = getLastButtonId();
        } else if (position > getLastButtonId()) {
            position = position - buttonAmount;
        }
        int nL = getDP(leftCoord.get(position));
        int nB = getDP(bottomCoord.get(position));
        int left = cL - nL;
        int bot = cB - nB;
        long time = 1000;

        if (rotationType == LEFTBUTTON) {
            if (cL == getDP(leftArrowLeft) && cB == getDP(leftArrowBottom)) {
                hide = false;
                visible = true;
                show = true;
            }
            if (nL == getDP(leftArrowLeft) && nB == getDP(leftArrowBottom)) {
                hide = false;
                visible = false;
                time = 0;
            }

            if (nL == getDP(rightArrowLeft)
                    && nB == getDP(rightArrowBottom)) {
                hide = true;
            }
        } else

        if (rotationType == RIGHTBUTTON) {
            if (cL == getDP(rightArrowLeft)
                    && cB == getDP(rightArrowBottom)) {
                hide = false;
                visible = true;
                show = true;
            }
            if (nL == getDP(leftArrowLeft) && nB == getDP(leftArrowBottom)) {
                hide = true;
            }

            if (nL == getDP(rightArrowLeft)
                    && nB == getDP(rightArrowBottom)) {
                hide = false;
                visible = false;
                show = false;
                time = 0;
            }
        }

        TranslateAnimation trans = new TranslateAnimation(left, 0, bot, 0);

        final int l = nL;
        final int b = nB;
        final ImageButton ib = button;
        final boolean isVisible = visible;
        final boolean isHide = hide;
        final boolean isShow = show;
        final int count = i;
        final RelativeLayout layout = main;
        button.clearAnimation();
        trans.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params;

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                params.leftMargin = l;
                params.topMargin = b;
                ib.setLayoutParams(params);

                if (isVisible) {
                    int tag = (Integer) ib.getTag();
                    ib.setImageResource(resourcesList[tag]);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                if (!isVisible) {
                    ib.setImageDrawable(null);
                }
            }
        });

        trans.setDuration(time);
        animationsSet.addAnimation(trans);
        if (show) {
            Animation animShow = new AlphaAnimation(.0f, 1f);
            animShow.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    // ib.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    // buttons.get(count).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });
            animShow.setDuration(1000);
            animationsSet.addAnimation(animShow);
        } else if (hide) {
            Animation hideShow = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, .0f);
            hideShow.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                }
            });
            hideShow.setDuration(1000);
            animationsSet.addAnimation(hideShow);

        }
        button.startAnimation(animationsSet);
    }

    if (rotationType == RIGHTBUTTON) {
        movementCount--;
    } else if (rotationType == LEFTBUTTON) {
        movementCount++;
    }

    if (movementCount < 0) {
        movementCount = getLastButtonId();
    } else if (movementCount > getLastButtonId()) {
        movementCount = 0;
    }
}
```